# Extending application to use on LAN

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am not a very experienced programmer. And I am facing technical issues in database servers.

I have developed a small standalone **C#** Application which is already in use.
It uses **SQLite** database. The database usage is not very heavy. Only a few form needs to be read and write to the database.

Now there is a requirement that it should be used on LAN.
I know that SQLite is not a good database option for client/server.

But keeping these points in mind should I change the database or not..

1. The application is **already using SQLite** and this is not a project from start.
2. The database usage is not very heavy. Only a few forms will be filled and data is written on the database.
3. At most **1-4** Pc's will be using the application simultaneously.

I had tried to install MS SQL server on my customers PC but then I am facing so many technical issues and it is taking a lot of time.

So I am thinking to stick with SQLite only.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the answer may vary depending on the structure of your application. For example, if you designed a Winform application that make call to the DB directly behind the button's click handler, or if you created a layered application maybe with Entity framework or similar, or X, or Y... Well, the path to your answer can change significantly.

Comment: I have my database layer different and business logic layer different.

Comment: I think you may be better asking a couple of specific questions regarding the actual technical issues you are running into, as this is possibly too broad for anyone to provide an answer you will find helpful/useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is your question *"Can I share a SQLite database between multiple workstations"*, or *"How to install SQL Server"*?

I'd say go with the last. SQLite even [promotes](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) the use of a client-server DMBS if you require multiple processes accessing the same database.

Comment: The link you provided was very helpful.  
And this statement in that link is particularly for me I think   
**But experience suggests that most applications need much less concurrency than their designers imagine** .  

So i think SQLite will do the job well. And I don't have to change the database.

Comment: Well then put your SQLite file on a shared folder and give it a go. However don't just read what you want to read, as the link also says: _"People who have a lot of experience with Windows tell me that file locking of network files is very buggy and is not dependable. If what they say is true, sharing an SQLite database between two or more Windows machines might cause unexpected problems"_.

Answer (score 0):

Installing MS SQL server can be pain; you have to ensure .NET framework is installed, windows service pack is installed and MSI has correct version. Still I would prefer going that way, because of robustness and reliability it promotes and rather write some robust installer to "make it happen".

You can of course, keep your current solution and write web service that will lock access to database to one-client & one-query at time only and rewrite your app to use this service instead of accessing db directly.

Btw. - Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition is working similar to SQLLite (in the terms ease of install), and it allows multiple connection to the same database (.sdf file)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb380177%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Since I will have to change a lot of code. I was thinking that if multiple write queries are made to SQLite then I will be getting a Connection Busy state. So then I can manage it in my application by checking the state. This will ensure proper working of the application.